# Building a buildroot package against target context

Tags: linux, buildroot

I am trying to build tcc as a package. But, it seems like tcc's build process wants to run an executable against the target environment/architecture [here](https://github.com/Tiny-C-Compiler/mirror-repository/blob/mob/Makefile#L264). I got it to work by patching the Makefile to chroot into target when running those binaries.

I am wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: »build tcc as a package« : Example "buildroot" → `$ rpmbuild -bb tcc.spec` ← ← `$ wget ftp://ftp.pbone.net/mirror/distrib-coffee.ipsl.jussieu.fr/mageia/distrib/9/SRPMS/core/release/tcc-0.9.27-9+git20200814.62c30a4a.mga9.src.rpm`  ..... No issues, tcc-0.9.27 , Fedora 39. .... For the github version `$ git clone https://github.com/LuaDist/tcc.git` this will do `$ ./configure && make && make test` , see README .